# Как объединить 2 таблицы MYSQL с id от одной из таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql

как объединить 2 таблицы с id от одной из таблиц?

Пробую так но выдает ошибку

нужно чтобы выводились все колонки обеих таблиц (кроме id таблицы от cronjob),  где id чтобы было от таблицы imports

SELECT *
FROM
  imports
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  cronjob
    ON imports.Id

Comment: ON должно содержать сравнение, а не просто поле.

Comment: прошу помочь, скинув правильный вариант, так как не силен в sql

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь вы не дописали SQL. Вам необходимо сравнить id из одной таблицы к id другой. Например, `SELECT * FROM imports FULL OUTER JOIN cronjob ON imports.Id = cronjob.Id`